# TTransportException when creating keyspace

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I'm using `cassandra-cli -h localhost` to create keyspace.

I tried this command: `create keyspace reddit with strategy_options = [{replication_factor:1}];` and this one: `create keyspace reddit with strategy_options = {replication_factor:1};`, but all I get is this:

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
```

I tried on Cassandra 1.1.6 and 1.2.2 on ArchLinux (built from AUR). (I'm running Cassandra with `systemctl start cassandra`).

Also, when I try to `use reddit;` **before** creating keyspace it returns `Keyspace 'reddit' not found.`, but **after** trying to create keyspace it returns `Login failure. Did you specify 'keyspace', 'username' and 'password'?`.

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention, but `create keyspace test;` works great, but when I'm creating keyspace with replication_factor, it throws the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using this query:

```
create keyspace reddit with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy' and strategy_options = [{replication_factor:1}];
```

I got here by reading /var/log/cassandra/system.log:

```
CustomTThreadPoolServer.java (line 217) Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.AbstractReplicationStrategy.createReplicationStrategy(AbstractReplicationStrategy.java:230)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.system_add_keyspace(CassandraServer.java:1342)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$system_add_keyspace.getResult(Cassandra.java:3960)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$system_add_keyspace.getResult(Cassandra.java:3948)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:199)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.AbstractReplicationStrategy.createReplicationStrategy(AbstractReplicationStrategy.java:226)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: replication_factor is an option for SimpleStrategy, not NetworkTopologyStrategy
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy.<init>(NetworkTopologyStrategy.java:66)
        ... 14 more
```